# Image Cover with LaTeX (on WinEdt)

Tags: graphics, covers

Any thoughts on how to put a full image (covering whole page) as a cover for a book I am writing on WinEdt (LaTeX)?

Answer (score 3):

OK solved using:

```
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{textblock*}{297mm}(0mm,0mm)
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{xxx.png}
\end{textblock*}
```

(Source: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=968)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the package "wallpaper".

`\ThisTileWallPaper{width}{height}{picturename}`